# Does PDO escape "%" and "_" today

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

there are old questions with same content, but I want to know the facts today.

So my question is: is pdo escpaing "%" and "_" in the meantime?

And if not: how did you solve the escaping in querys with a LIKE.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Does PDO escape “%” and “_” today

No. And won't be doing so in the future. Simply because there is no reason to escape such useful wildcard characters.

> how did you solve the escaping in querys with a LIKE.

Not in the query you mean but in the supplied string, to avoid incorrect results from LIKE operator?

```
addCslashes($data, '%_');
```

Comment: So you put this AddCslashes around each input data? I would like that, because i wan to use my own pdo class and would like to add this. So there is another question: can i use: SELECT * FROM x WHERE y LIKE %:z%. I thought that wont work and the % have to be in the :z.

Comment: Any reason I would put this AddCslashes around each input data?